# Python code is giving WA for CHEFSQ for codeshef?

Tags: python-3.x

```
t = int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    n = int(input())
    N = input().split()
    f = int(input())
    F = input().split()
    ans = True
    for i in range(len(N)):
        if N[i:i+f] == F:
            print('Yes')
            ans = False
            break
    if ans:
        print('No')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I also your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please visit http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more information on formatting. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Actually there has been some problems with the PROBLEM. It asks for substring in the statement but will accept solution having F sequence as it's sub-sequence.
Consider running your queries as test cases on my accepted code:

```
t=int(input())
while t>0:
t-=1
n=int(input())
s=input().split()
q=int(input())
seq=input().split()
st,ans=0,0
sig=1
for i in range(len(seq)):
    for j in range(st,len(s)):
        if seq[i]==s[j]:
            st=j+1
            ans+=1
            break
    else:
        sig=0
    if sig==0:
        break
print("Yes" if ans==len(seq) else "No")
```